# Why do I always have to run apt-get update twice? Or do I?

Tags: debian, apt

Every time I run `apt-get update`, I get the following message (the exact duplicate package is different depending on the last entry in `sources.list`):

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main armel Packages 
(/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_squeeze_main_binary-armel_Packages)
```

If I run `apt-get update` again, it's fine. What's going on?

Comment: Perhaps there are duplicated lines in sources.list....?

Comment: @Jivings There are not

Comment: @TomMedley did you remap the keyboard?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, these warnings are completely benign. You could simply just run update once and ignore the output.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This bug is specific to the RasPi Debian Squeeze image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there is a bug in the image. `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains 2 lines that look like this

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main non-free
```

To solve your problem, delete the first one.

Whilst the lines aren't exact duplicate, they do specify duplicate repositories.